# How to associate jsonb type field and a table in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have two tables in my Postgre database.

- Projects (field name and type)

  ```
  id   name    customers
  uuid varchar jsonb
  ```
- customers (field name and type)

  ```
  id   name
  uuid varchar
  ```

And here's the project model defined.

```
const project = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Project = sequelize.define('project', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    customers: {
      type: DataTypes.JSONB,
      defaultValue: [],
      allowNull: true,
    }
  })
  return Project
}

export default project
```

And here's the project model defined.

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  return sequelize.define(
    'customer',
    {
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: true,
      },
  )}
}
```

So the customers field in project table has json type values.
For example (array of uuid):

```
customers = ["0000-0000-0000-0000", "1111-1111-1111-1111"];
```

In this case, how to add associations between projects and customers table?

Ideally, I want to include the id matching customers while finding all projects like the following.

```
const getProjects = async () => {
  try {
    return await models.Projects.findAll({
      include: [{
        model: models.Customers // It should include all customers for a project
      }]
    })
  } catch (error) {
    throw error
  }
}
```

Hope to hear from you soon.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your data model is wrong and will only cause trouble for you. If you want to model a many-to-many relationship between two entities, create a “junction table” with foreign keys to both related tables. The primary key is the combination of both foreign keys.